# Neo4J get id relation from url

Tags: neo4j, relationship

In Neo4j, I am returning a list of nodes, from which- in a loop- I read their ids and, for all of them, I am reading their relationships using (in this example I am using node_id=3071):

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3071/relationships/out
```

The JSON output (for a specified value of id) is as follows:

```
[{'end': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3070',
'extensions': {},
'self': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/11101',
'property': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/11101/properties/{key}',
'type': 'IS', 'properties': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/relationship/11101/properties',
'data': {},
'start': 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/3071'}]
```

We observe that our node 3071 is connected to 3070. The result is, however, in an obfuscated
form rather than in a simple form. How can I get this 3070 (the ids of the connected nodes) without using the regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that you don't.

Your particular REST query here is asking for relationships.  The node ID is the property of a node, which you wouldn't expect would be provided when asking for relationships.

[If you ask for the node](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-nodes.html#rest-api-get-node) then the JSON that the server responds with will include this:

```
"metadata" : {
   "id" : 4147,
   "labels" : [ "Person" ]
}
```

But that only applies to fetching information about nodes.

You might also be using an old version though.   In the [current documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-relationships.html#rest-api-get-incoming-relationships) for that same REST call, you'd expect to see this metadata object with an ID for the relationship, but it wasn't included in your sample response from your server.

Consider using the REST API to fetch the URLs described by `start` and `end`, and you'll get back JSON that includes this `metadata` with an `id` property - that is your answer, without regular expressions.

**EDIT**:  As Michael Hunger below suggests - if you're willing to step away from the JSON you can get what you want by running a simple cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)-->(other) WHERE id(n) in {ids} RETURN id(other),other
```

Specifying the `other` param to be `{"ids":[3071, 3072, 3073]}`.  But like the other solution (fetching the nodes individually) it requires an extra call; you can't get the information out of the response to the query for incident relationships.

Comment: I actually would use Cypher to do what you're trying to do: `MATCH (n)-->(other) WHERE id(n) in {ids} RETURN id(other),other` params would be `{"ids":[3071, 3072, 3073]}`

Comment: Edited to include this as well.  I think the original question threw me a bit because it seemed OP was trying to get this info out of the query for incident rels.  There are probably a bunch of different ways to get the node ID (but all would presume the need for additional calls)